# How to doublecheck my SSH credentials on WIndows?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am a member of my company organization. SSH keys associated with my account. Nothing works as expected.
I am trying to push my branch

```
$ git push -u origin mirispc
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I cloned my comp private repo(details changed for security reasons)

```
origin  git@github.com:mycomp/repo-pr (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:mycomp/repo-pr (push)
```

I will copy just part of the  `ssh -Tv git@github.com` due to length

```
    OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-22beb20a
    debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-22beb20a
    debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

And 
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/jholmes/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
....
Hi JHolmes! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
```

I am running all of these from Git Bash.

What should I try now?

Comment: What was the root cause in your case (from those I mentioned in my answer)?

Comment: @VonC Can you take a look?GitHub does not provide shell access,how it comes?

Comment: That is expected: there is never direct interactive shell access with ssh for remote Git hosting services like GitHub. It is just a way to ensure you are recognized/authenticated as you by GitHub, which is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that https://github.com/mycomp/repo-pr does exist (meaning the case, uper or lower, of the URL is correct)

Second, check that you are correctly authenticated by GitHub through SSH:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

Third, double-check with your org admins that you are indeed a member of said organization.

On Windows, make sure you don't have a GIT_SSH environment variable set.